# Checkboxes connected to database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, checkbox

I'm stuck with a problem regarding checkboxes from a WPF application to a SQL database.

I've arrived at a point where I can update the value of a specific item into the database but I can only update the value or from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0, I'm searching for an IF Statement kind of thing, and I think I'm near the solution but the code isn't working and gives me the error

> "there's an error near ="

Please help.

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    sqliteCon.Open();

    if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
    var currentRowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid1.CurrentItem);//PER IDENTIFICARE LA LINEA CORRENTE

    //PROVA5
    string q = @"UPDATE tabList
         SET selection = (CASE Prova
                            WHEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 0 '
                            THEN tabList.selection.Value = ' 1'
                            ELSE tabList.selection.Value = ' 0 '
                        END)
     WHERE idL = @CURRENT";


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CURRENT", currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Dato Modificato");
    }

    sqliteCon.Close();
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want single quotes around the values 0 and 1 in your query since they are BIT values.

Comment: i have an entire column into my db with values 0 that i want to change to 1 if i click on the respective checkbox or to 0 if the item is checked yet

Comment: Let's see if we can get what you have posted working and then we can see about modifying what you have to fit your need.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL statement can't see the value of the checkbox.  Like that of your parameter for the ID value, you will need to pull that from the checkbox and apply THAT to the sql query

```
var flagVal = WPFControl.selection.value == 1 ? 0 : 1;

//PROVA5
var q = @"UPDATE tabList
             SET selection = @NEWFLAG
             WHERE idL = @CURRENT";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NEWFLAG", flagVal);

... rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        sqliteCon.Open();

        if (sqliteCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {

            var currentRowIndex = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(dataGrid1.CurrentItem);//PER IDENTIFICARE LA LINEA CORRENTE


            string q = @"UPDATE tabList
                         SET selection = (CASE 
                                            WHEN (SELECT selection FROM tabList where idL = @CURRENT) = 0
                                            THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0
                                          END)
                         WHERE idL = @CURRENT";


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, sqliteCon);
            currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CURRENT", currentRowIndex);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Dato Modificato");

        }
        sqliteCon.Close();
    }
```